# KE= 1/2 mass times velocity squared or speed squared?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, vectors

I'm currently studying Physics 101 and I'm kinda lost on the subject of velocity and speed

I know that the speed is a scalar quantity which only has a magnitude, and velocity is a vector quantity which has a magnitude & direction.

but what does ($v$) refers to in $KE = 1/2 mv^2$?

I suppose its speed because we don't care about the direction in kinetic energy and in work as well; however, the internet says its velocity but I don't know why.

Comment: Remember that velocity is relative to some frame of reference. So for a first thing, think about what the frame is that you are measuring the KE relative to.

Comment: @zeta-band And so is speed...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ok, good luck

Comment: *"however, the internet says its velocity"* - voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both.

Let velocity be $\vec{v}$. Speed is $|\vec{v}|$. The term in KE is

$$\frac{1}{2}m\vec{v}^2=\frac{1}{2}m(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})=\frac{1}{2}m|\vec{v}|^2$$

Comment: This does demonstrate a tendency which frustrated me in classes, to use "v" to describe a speed, rather than "s."  As this answer shows, it's not that they used a "v" to describe a speed, so much as they got lazy drawing the || for the magnitude of the velocity vector!

Comment: @CortAmmon Unfortunately for you, this tendency doesn't really go away. The notation $\vec{x}^2$ to denote a vector dotted with itself is prevalent through most of physics.

Comment: It's not laziness. The notation $\vec v{}^2$ (or $\boldsymbol v^2$) is perfectly unambiguous and standard. At this point inserting $|\,|$ is just pedantry. Why would you use *more* symbols than necessary, especially when they add literally no information?

Comment: @CortAmmon Well, $s$ is *obviously* used for "displacement" so it wasn't available for "speed"...

Comment: @CortAmmon And here I thought that $\vec{v}^2$ would be zero because $\vec{v} \times \vec{v}$ is a squared vector quantity. ;)

Comment: Can't follow @Cort Ammon in terms of dictionary. In my language for instance we have a single word for both. Is even not the case of having a letter already occupieds. But he is right. It is incorrect to write 1/2m*(velocity vector)^2.

Comment: @Alchimista Incorrect according to whom? Landau and Lifshitz definitely use this notation, for instance.

Comment: @probably_someone is not matter of notation if you want.  One can simplify alot especially when every single character counts. Of course you cannot do so much wrong with ( vector )^2. But you should agree that the question above wouldn't be had posed....

Comment: In fact the question doesn't really ask anything :)

Comment: @CortAmmon Speed *is* the magnitude of the velocity vector. $v=\left|\vec v\right|$ is very standard notation.

Comment: @Chris Oh, I'm definitely aware of it.  It just causes me problems.  I've had python programs which crashed deep in their bowels, with horribly cryptic error messages.  When we finally backed out the problem, its that a user inputted a vector when it needed to be a scalar, and it took half a simulation's execution time before that detail finally caused an error.

Comment: @CortAmmon That's less a problem with physics notation as it is a consequence of dynamic types in python. In C++ that wouldn't happen, by definition.

Comment: @probably_someone It also wouldn't happen if someone wrote "speed" when the meant "speed" and "velocity" when they meant "velocity." =)  For the amount they beat that into us in high school, it sure didn't change anything in the industry.  Kind of like the metric system ;-)

Comment: @probably_someone Oh, trust me, if you try hard enough you can make things like that happen in C++, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

A little about the wording of the question: as per definition, the physical quantity called „velocity” is mathematically described by a real vector space-valued function $$ \vec{v} : I\subset \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n. $$ 
In mathematics, vectors can be added, multiplied by scalars, but never raised to a power, be it 2,3, $\pi^e$, or any other number. Using a vector space, one can define external operations, such as an inner product $$ \langle,\rangle :\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R.$$ With help of this and help of the well-defined square function in the field of real numbers, one has:
$$ \langle \vec{v},\vec{v}\rangle =: ||\vec{v}||^2,$$ where the quantity being squared is called norm (length) of the vector. The norm of the velocity vector is called (instantaneous) speed.

By flagrant abuse of mathematical notation, $||\vec{v}||^2$ is typically written as $\vec v^2$, or a little better as $|\vec v|^2$ which has led people to believe the velocity vector can be squared.

Bottom line, KE = 1/2 times mass of particle times (instantaneous) speed raised to the power of two.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.  In the formula $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, direction does not matter, it is merely calculating the energy the object possess at that point in time, in whatever direction.